# ASP.NET Core EF6 Identity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am creating a new project in ASP.NET Core with EF6 as the ORM - Note *not* **EF Core**.

I am having issues trying to configure the Identity Store.

Here is what I have so far:

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This line is causing me the headache. AddEntityFrameworkStores is for EF Core and not the full version of EF 6.

How do I reference the underlying data store for EF6

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have overridden the default data type of Id for ApplicationUser and IdentityRole.

Try `AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, int>()`, or the with type that you have overridden.